# How do I put the HTML content from another page into a string?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know that I can use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to put the current page into a string, but I need to get other pages on the same website into a string from a certain, different page. The pages are php files, and my function is running from the parent index.php.

The ultimate goal for this is a site-wide search function.

Comment: use ajax and get a text respanse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery has a really useful function called $.get().  Say I wanted to get the page example.com and put it into a string, I would use:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com', function(data){

  //The local variable 'data' now has example.com stored inside of it here.

});
```

If you wanted to do this server-side using PHP, you can use file_get_contents, like so:

```
<?php
    $otherPagesHTML = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
?>
```

Comment: Can I use PHP in my script file (which is a .js)?

Comment: I do not believe so with .js files, since php files need the .php extension.  However, you could do this: <script src="http://example.com/script.js.php"></script>.  Then, edit your script on-the-fly with PHP.  If you need help doing something specific, discord me at Creater246#3027, and I can help you.